# mbed persistent flash storage

Tags: persistent-storage, mbed, flash-memory

I'm working on a project using mbed studio and NUCLEO-L432KC board.

I have a need to store configuration values to persistent memory on the device.
I have successfully wrote the configuration the the last flash sector and I am also able to read it.
It also survives a reboot, so this is working as expected.

However when modifying the code and reflashing the device, apparently the whole device is erased. This means that everytime I click 'run program' in the mbed studio all the config data is erased.

Is there some way of telling mbed studio to not erase the whole chip? mbed studio does not seem to have options for this, or maybe I just can't find them?

Or is there some other solution that I could use to store the config data (without extra HW).

Thanks!